# android set time in datetime picker using milliseconds

Tags: android, datetimepicker, android-datepicker

I have a time in milliseconds say 1384841520328, i need to convert and set in datepicker and timepicker, i converted the time from datetime picker as,

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth(), 
timePicker.getCurrentHour(), timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
NewTimeForAlert = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Now i want to convert back those milliseconds to datetime picker format, i am using android's default widget.

Comment: It's not the default Widget, but gave a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847623/how-to-pick-a-second-using-timepicker-android It may solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar2.setTimeInMillis(1384841520328);
timePicker.setCurrentHour(calendar2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)); // or Calendar.HOUR for 12 hour format
timePicker.setCurrentMinute(calendar2.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Comment: So use `Calendar.HOUR` instead of `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`