# How to change the order of the NumberPickers in DatePickerDialog

Tags: android

[image]

I want to swap the Month And Date (Spinners). I want to send the Date column (Spinner) to the left and the Month column (Spinner) to the middle. Is it possible?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584934/custom-datepicker-in-android

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 9):

According to notes in the source, the order of those `NumberPicker`s is determined by the system-wide date format chosen by the user, falling back on a determination of the best order given the user's locale. There is no public method available to easily change this. However, I've figured out a way to change the order regardless.

In the following example, we obtain the IDs for the `DatePickerDialog`'s `NumberPicker`s from the System Resources. The names for these identifiers I found by examining [the layout file](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/date_picker.xml/) for the `DatePicker` class.

Once we've got the IDs, we find the `NumberPicker`s and their parent `LinearLayout` in the dialog just like we would any other `View`. We can then remove the spinners from the layout, and add them back in any order desired. The `DatePicker` class uses the same method to reorder the spinners, and some of the code below is pulled from its source.

After adding back each spinner, we need to call `setImeOptions()` with it and its new index in the order. This will correct the focus chain and keyboard feedback for the spinners' input `TextView`s.

This all got a little unwieldy, so I wrapped it up in a couple of methods. You need only call the `orderDate()` method after your dialog is shown, with a `char` array indicating the desired date order. For example:

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(...);
...
dialog.show();

orderDate(dialog, new char[]{'d', 'm', 'y'});
```

We keep an `int` constant for the number of spinners, simplifying some of the code pulled from the source:

```
private static final int SPINNER_COUNT = 3;

private void orderDate(DatePickerDialog dialog, char[] ymdOrder) {
    if(!dialog.isShowing()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Dialog must be showing");
    }

    final int idYear = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("year", "id", "android");
    final int idMonth = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("month", "id", "android");
    final int idDay = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android");
    final int idLayout = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("pickers", "id", "android");

    final NumberPicker spinnerYear = (NumberPicker) dialog.findViewById(idYear);
    final NumberPicker spinnerMonth = (NumberPicker) dialog.findViewById(idMonth);
    final NumberPicker spinnerDay = (NumberPicker) dialog.findViewById(idDay);
    final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(idLayout);

    layout.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < SPINNER_COUNT; i++) {
        switch (ymdOrder[i]) {
            case 'y':
                layout.addView(spinnerYear);
                setImeOptions(spinnerYear, i);                  
                break;
            case 'm':
                layout.addView(spinnerMonth);
                setImeOptions(spinnerMonth, i);
                break;
            case 'd':
                layout.addView(spinnerDay);
                setImeOptions(spinnerDay, i);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid char[] ymdOrder");
        }
    }
}

private void setImeOptions(NumberPicker spinner, int spinnerIndex) {
    final int imeOptions;
    if (spinnerIndex < SPINNER_COUNT - 1) {
        imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT;
    }
    else {
        imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE;
    }
    int idPickerInput = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("numberpicker_input", "id", "android");
    TextView input = (TextView) spinner.findViewById(idPickerInput);
    input.setImeOptions(imeOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on @Mike M. solution I wrote an extension function in Kotlin.

**Example:**

```
datePicker.formatDate("dmy") // show picker in Day, Month, Year format
```

**Kotlin extension function:**

```
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo
import android.widget.DatePicker
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.NumberPicker
import android.widget.TextView

private const val SPINNER_COUNT = 3

/**
 * Changes the [DatePicker] date format.
 * Example: dmy will show the date picker in day, month, year order
 * */
fun DatePicker.formatDate(ymdOrder: String) {
  val system = Resources.getSystem()
  val idYear = system.getIdentifier("year", "id", "android")
  val idMonth = system.getIdentifier("month", "id", "android")
  val idDay = system.getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")
  val idLayout = system.getIdentifier("pickers", "id", "android")
  val spinnerYear = findViewById<View>(idYear) as NumberPicker
  val spinnerMonth = findViewById<View>(idMonth) as NumberPicker
  val spinnerDay = findViewById<View>(idDay) as NumberPicker
  val layout = findViewById<View>(idLayout) as LinearLayout
  layout.removeAllViews()
  for (i in 0 until SPINNER_COUNT) {
    when (ymdOrder[i]) {
      'y' -> {
        layout.addView(spinnerYear)
        setImeOptions(spinnerYear, i)
      }
      'm' -> {
        layout.addView(spinnerMonth)
        setImeOptions(spinnerMonth, i)
      }
      'd' -> {
        layout.addView(spinnerDay)
        setImeOptions(spinnerDay, i)
      }
      else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid char[] ymdOrder")
    }
  }
}

private fun setImeOptions(spinner: NumberPicker, spinnerIndex: Int) {
  val imeOptions: Int = if (spinnerIndex < SPINNER_COUNT - 1) {
    EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT
  } else {
    EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
  }
  val idPickerInput: Int = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("numberpicker_input", "id", "android")
  val input = spinner.findViewById<View>(idPickerInput) as TextView
  input.imeOptions = imeOptions
}
```